# Invoke same method on all active instances of a stateless service

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateless

What is the best way to invoke the same method on all active instances of a stateless service in SFC? 
I mean doing something similar to below, just on ALL active instances:

```
var service = ServiceProxy.Create<IMyService>("<my-service-uri>");
await service.MyServiceMethod();
```

Comment: What do you mean by invoking a method? Are you trying to make remoting call to a service or you are talking about HTTP call?

Comment: I mean a remoting call for each active instance. Question extended to provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately looks like there is no way to send remoting request to the particular service instance / replica.

According to the documentation of [ServiceProxy.Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.services.remoting.client.serviceproxy.create?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_ServiceFabric_Services_Remoting_Client_ServiceProxy_Create__1_System_Uri_Microsoft_ServiceFabric_Services_Client_ServicePartitionKey_Microsoft_ServiceFabric_Services_Communication_Client_TargetReplicaSelector_System_String_) method there is a very limited control over target instance / replica selection (it is strict to the [TargetReplicaSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.services.communication.client.targetreplicaselector?view=azure-dotnet) enumeration).

Comment: I was hoping I can get the list of all instances, the same way I can iterate over nodes, partitions etc using FabricClient & ServicePartitionResolver. Then I'd call the method using remoting one-by-one. I'd probably need to use smth else than regular ServiceProxy... class

Comment: @filip as far as I know there is no way to communicate using remoting without **ServiceProxy**. In case you will found the way here is the code to get information about each replica (including its id and more) - `var client = new FabricClient(); foreach (var partition in await client.QueryManager.GetPartitionListAsync(new Uri("<service-name>"))) { foreach (var replica in await client.QueryManager.GetReplicaListAsync(partition.PartitionInformation.Id)) { // Here you have replica information } }`