# How to invoke a method in all Service Fabric nodes?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have a stateless service where I have a method and inside which I am creating a class instance.
I have published the service in multiple nodes.
So when I am calling that method from another service, the method will invoke in one of the nodes. So the instance will be available in only that node.
If the node is down, I am losing the class instance.

Is there any way to invoke a method in all Service Fabric nodes?
Or is it possible in stateful services?

Answer (score 1):

If your service have to persist state between failures, you should not use Stateless Services, you should use Stateful Services and put the data you have to persist in a Reliable Collection.

The other approach, if your Class\Object will process something when it receives a call, you could make it an Actor, and the actor state will be replicated to other nodes, if the actor goes down, it's state will be reload when a new instance take over.

If you really need to use a stateless service, you should then persist this class in a cache, like Redis or Memcache.

For you main question, take a look at this other SO questions: [Invoke same method on all active instances of a stateless service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51243097/invoke-same-method-on-all-active-instances-of-a-stateless-service)